# Python - changing content of .txt files from folder and saving in new folder

Tags: python

I need to change some key words in multiple .txt files, using dictionary strucure for this. Then, save changed files in new localization. I write code attached below, but when I run it is warking all the time, and when I break it there is only one empty file cretead.

```
import os
import os.path
from pathlib import Path

dir_path = Path("C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\scripts_new")

#loading pair of words from txt file into dictionary

myfile = open("C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\Python\\dictionary.txt")
data_dict = {}
for line in myfile:
    k, v = line.strip().split(':')
    data_dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()
 
myfile.close()

# Get the list of all files and directories
path_dir = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\scripts"


# iterate over files in
# that directory

for filename in os.listdir(path_dir):
    f = os.path.join(path_dir, filename)
    name = os.path.join(filename)
    text_file = open(f)

  #read whole file to a string
sample_string = text_file.read()

 # Iterate over all key-value pairs in dictionary

for key, value in data_dict.items():

    # Replace key character with value character in string
    
    sample_string = sample_string.replace(key, value)


with open(os.path.join(dir_path,name), "w") as file1:
    toFile = input(sample_string)
    file1.write(toFile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, with a little different approach. Maybe this code might be usefull for someone:

```
import os

#loading pair of words from txt file into dictionary
myfile = open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Python\\dictionary.txt")
data_dict = {}
for line in myfile:
    k, v = line.strip().split(':')
    data_dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()
 
myfile.close()

sourcepath = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\scripts\\")

for file in sourcepath:
        input_file =  "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\scripts\\" + file
        print('Conversion is ongoing for: ' + input_file)
        with open(input_file, 'r') as input_file:
            filedata = input_file.read()
        destination_path =  "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\scripts_new\\"+ file

         # Iterate over all key-value pairs in dictionary

        for key, value in data_dict.items():

            filedata = filedata.replace(key,value)

        with open(destination_path,'w') as file:
            file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: To improve this and future answers, it is best to include an explanation of how and why your solution works, so it can aid others in the future. Code-only answers may be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I think your problem might actually be use of the line

```
toFile = input(sample_string)
```

As that'll halt the program awaiting a user input

Anyway, it could probably do with a little organisation into functions. Even this below is a bit... meh.

```
import os
import os.path
from pathlib import Path

dir_path = Path("C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\scripts_new")

# -----------------------------------------------------------
def load_file(fileIn):
    #loading pair of words from txt file into dictionary

    with open(fileIn) as myfile:
        data_dict = {}
        for line in myfile:
            k, v = line.strip().split(':')
            data_dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()

    return data_dict

# -----------------------------------------------------------
def work_all_files(starting_dir, moved_dir, data_dict):
   # Iterate over files within the dir - note non recursive
    for filename in os.listdir(starting_dir):
        f = os.path.join(starting_dir, filename)

        with open(f, 'r') as f1:
            #read whole file to a string
            sample_string = f1.read()

        new_string = replace_strings(sample_string, data_dict)

    with open(os.path.join(moved_dir, filename), "w") as file1:
        file1.write(new_string)

# -----------------------------------------------------------
def replace_strings(sample_string, data_dict):
    # Iterate over all key-value pairs in dictionary
    # and if they exist in sample_string, replace them

    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        # Replace key character with value character in string
        sample_string = sample_string.replace(key, value)

    return sample_string

# -----------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the dict-val pairings first
    data_dict = load_file("C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\Python\\dictionary.txt")

    #Then run over all the files within dir
    work_all_files("C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\scripts", "C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\new_scripts", data_dict)
```

We could have housed all this in a class and then transported a few variables around using the instance (i.e. "self") - would have been cleaner. But first step is learning to break things into functions.

Comment: A little bit helpfull, but this not solve my problem.

Comment: Ah, I misread you - saved in *different* locations. I was just overwriting. It was working grand for me. Modified answer